# Reflection/Normal coordinates issue

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an issue with the normal/reflection coordinates, the idea is to make the part look like this.
[image]

but ends up looking like this
[image]

The idea is to make it look like in the game. What I want to do is make the texture not deform or stretch, like a flat surface. I looked everywhere but I couldn't find how.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, are you trying to get the texture to look a certain way?

Comment: the model was imported from ssb4 wii u, the insides of the dress look like space , in game the texture doesn't deform or strech while you move the camera, what i want to do is make the texture to look flat, like you see in the first image...

Comment: Did you try to switch to user orthographic mode with the camera?

Comment: It looks like in the game, it's is orthographic view, not perspective.

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Hmm, u could try recalculating normals, unsubdividing with ctrl+e, or it could just look that way because it's not rendered?? I could ask questions but I don't know. Blender can be very frustrating sometimes. U don't have to upload a file but all I can do is ask questions..

Comment: If you have the texture, you can use nodes to get the certain look you want